# OnItemClickListener is not working in navigation drawer

Tags: android, xml, listview, navigation-drawer

i have created a navigation drawer and it is working fine and all the attributes of listview is showing but when i implements OnItemClickListener it is not performing the actions

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), array[position] + "is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    selectItem(position);
```

here is the full code,

```
package com.hamza.aurasalon;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener  ,OnClickListener {

private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ListView listView1; 
//,listView2;
String[] array =  null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setUpAttributes();

}

private void setUpAttributes() {
listView1= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerList1);
    //listView2= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerList2);
    array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mumtazFeatures1);
    listView1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array));
    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(this);

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), array[position] + "is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    selectItem(position);


}
```

xml code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawerFrame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>

<ListView
    android:background="#FF8800"
    android:id="@+id/drawerList1"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left">

</ListView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawerList2"
    android:background="#FFCC00"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:entries="@array/mumtazFeatures2" >
</ListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: there is no error showing. i want to know why the message is not showing when i click the item of listview

Comment: http://www.coderzheaven.com/tag/onitemclicklistener/ check this it may help u

Comment: Have you solved this problem? Googling brought me here.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
       listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), array[position] + "is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  selectItem(position);
            }
        });
```

Comment: did you try other listview call methods, like setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {})